# How to show/hide a div animatedly?

Tags: javascript

It is a dumb question, but I can't figure it out..

I want to show the div smoothly (slide down) when a link is clicked and hide it (slide up) when any other part of the page is click or the page is scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slideToggle, easier for you:

**[JSBIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/orutav/1/)**

**[Slide Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, you can work with **[`.slideDown('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)** method for example.

Usage:

```
$( 'a#myLink' ).click( function() {
    $( '#myDiv' ).slideDown( 'fast' );
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/UH4tD/) demo.

Comment: please elaborate.. actually, I don't know javascript well.. So, it'd be great if you give me the syntax